# Where is `helm-pdfgrep`?

Tags: helm, pdf

I have recently installed `helm` but haven't gotten very far with using it so far. I noticed that I can run the command `helm-pdfgrep-help` and it shows me a list of keybindings. But I don't have a `helm-pdfgrep` (or `pdfgrep-help` for that matter).

What's the deal? The idea of using helm to search text in my pdf library sounds extremely useful. But a quick search on the web does not lead me to think `helm-pdfgrep` even exists.

Comment: It seems not exist for me.. I'm just using isearch now. `(define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "C-s") 'isearch-forward)`   Have you found other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `ag 'define.*pdf.*grep'` (use `grep` instead of `ag` if you prefer) in the `elpa/` directory returns this:

```
helm-20150226.818/helm-locate.el
99:    (define-key map (kbd "M-g p")   'helm-ff-run-pdfgrep)

helm-20150226.818/helm-files.el
297:    (define-key map (kbd "M-g p")         'helm-ff-run-pdfgrep)

helm-20150226.818/helm-grep.el
229:    (define-key map (kbd "C-c ?")    'helm-pdfgrep-help)
```

So the command to run `pdfgrep` using `helm` would be `helm-ff-run-pdfgrep`. Note that you need to have [`pdfgrep`](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) installed on your system for this to work.

### Update

You should be able to find out the same using `apropos-command` or `C-h a pdfgrep RET`. Another command you can called interactively is `helm-do-pdfgrep`.

*I was unable to do so because I don't use `helm` and didn't `require` it but I had it installed.*

Answer (score 1):

To search pdf files, you need pick up these pdf files firstly via helm's file browser, i.e., `helm-find-files`, then launch pdf specific action (such as `pdfgrep`) there. The point is `helm-find-files` is the entry point, so there is no needs to make `helm-pdfgrep/grep/git-grep/ack/ag/pt/zgrep` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the deal? The idea of using helm to search text in my pdf library sounds extremely useful.

To search through multiple pdf files with pdfgrep you first use `helm-find-files`, then type any pattern to narrow the file list down to files you want to search, then press `M-a` to select all, then press `M-g p` to call `helm-ff-run-pdfgrep`, and finally type the grep search pattern and wait for results.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the results from kaushalmodi's answer, I'm thinking that there is unfortunately no standalone helm command for directly searching the content of multiple PDFs. But I did find that if I select a PDF using `helm-locate` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, there is an option on the list to use `pdfgrep` on that individual file using <kbd>F9</kbd>.

(Once I figured that out, I then tried to see if the shortcuts I saw listed from `helm-pdfgrep-help` would be useful. But now, `helm-pdfgrep-help` is just giving me an error: `No buffer named *helm*`.)